# Angular 4 - Error: No provider for HttpParams

Tags: angular

Scratching my head on this error. 'Error: No provider for HttpParams!'
Migrating from Http to HttpClient.
Imported HttpClientModule in app.module.ts and made it a member in @NgModule -> imports

There is still an import for HttpModule in app.module.ts. Can it be clashing with the new HttpClientModule?

In my service I have:

```
import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpParams} from "@angular/common/http";
```

Can someone please enlighten me as to why this is happening?
TIA,
Pedro.

Comment: when is the error appearing? when you want to start the service or on a specific call? can you share your logs?

Comment: Are you trying to inject `HttpParams` in your constructor? Perhaps you are injecting `HttpParams` instead of `HttpClient`

Comment: @LLai yes that's exactly it:
in my service's constructor I have: private params: HttpParams

that's what throwing the error.
Btw I need a class's member for storing params to be available throughout the remaining logic

Comment: the params should be used like `let params = new HttpParams().append('myParam', 'myValue');`

Comment: why are you trying to inject HttpParams? makes no sense

Comment: Does it show I'm new to angular? ;)

Thanks for all the help guys! :)

Comment: Thanks @LLai. It helped

Answer (score 3):

You are getting error for `HttpClient` so, you are missing `HttpClientModule` for that.

you should import it in "app.module.ts" file like this:

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
```

and mention it in the `NgModule` decorator like this:

```
 @NgModule({
   ...
   imports:[ HttpClientModule ]
   ...
 })
```

if this even doesn't work try clearing cookies of the browser and try restarting your server. Hopefully it may work, I was getting the same error.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using this `[params: HttpParams]` in your constructor, please remove it from the constructor.

```
import {HttpClient, HttpParams, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MarksService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private params: HttpParams) {}
}
```